# How to get parts of title as links to file in new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is how I make a table of the files in a directory, they will be pdf or images, my first goal is to get just a part of title (which will be separated as I like lets say `number_nam_company_color.pdf`) and I have to take those informations to a table as links, when clicked they open in a window like with a button, and I'm not sure if I'm getting those files the right way.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      
        <title>Aceuil</title>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div >
            <div >
<table class="grey">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>number</th>
    <th>nam</th>
    <th>company</th>
    <th>color</th>
    <th>date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<?php 
$dirname = 'myfiles'; 
$dir = opendir($dirname); 
while($file = readdir($dir)) { 
  if($file != '.' && $file != '..' && !is_dir($dirname.$file)) { 
?>
    <td>
<?php
    echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
 
?>
 </td>
<td>
<?php
    echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
 
?>
 </td>
 <td>
<?php
    echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
 
?>
 </td>
 <td>
<?php
    echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
 
?>
 </td>
 <td>
<?php
    echo "filectime($dirname . '/' . $file))";
 
?>
 </td>
 

</tr>
 <?php  
      }
     } 

  closedir($dir); 
   
    ?>
   
  

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is this code not working, or not providing the result you're looking for? If not, what are you expecting, and what do you see instead? Please be specific.

Comment: Use scandir. http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php, you don't need to open files, but operate with file paths...

Comment: my echo should get just a part of the title, thats my question

Answer (score 0):

t worked with this :

```html
$data = "$file";
list($numero,$nom,$marque,$couleur) = explode("_", $data);
echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$numero.'</a>';//in the same way i can get anything i want from the title
echo '<a href="'.$dirname.'/'.$file.'">'.$nom.'</a>';
```

and i want to open that pdf file in a window not with chrome?